# How do I use UIPath to Query a SQLite DB?

Tags: sqlite, uipath

I was able to create a connection within UIPath to the SQLite DB thanks to a previous post but now I can't seem to find where I can query the database or how to do this safely.  Do I still use SQL querying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use SQL Language in the UIPath Activity.

Now that you have the DB connection, you will want to pull in the data and manipulate the tables
Drag in a Database > ExecuteQuery activity
Click on Configure Connection.
Under Existing Database Connection, enter the Connection you just created previously
In the edit query, you can put in pure SQL.  Such as Select * from 
Everything in the query must be a string.
What this should return is a datatable.  Name your Datatable output accordingly